# awk print with a condition expression with a ternary operator

Tags: awk, gawk

Sample input:

```
1:2:3:0:5
1:2:3::5
```

Awk processing:

```
$ echo -e "1:2:3:0:5\n1:2:3::5"|awk -F: '{if($4!="") print NR,$4; else print NR,"-"}'
1 0
2 -
```

Question: can above be run in a short if notation? I tried something like this but it does not return output as above.

```
$ echo -e "1:2:3:0:5\n1:2:3::5"|awk -F: '{print NR,($4 ? $4 : "-")}'
1 -
2 -
```

Answer (score 3):

`0` is evaluated as `false` and by condition `$4 ? $4 : "-"` it comes to `"-"`.
To check for empty fourth field the condition `$4 != ""` should be specified.

```
awk -F':' '{ print NR, ($4 != ""? $4 : "-") }' file
```